# Non-Isomorphic Graphs with the same number of edges and vertices

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I'm new to graph theory and was wondering:

Can two graphs with every vertex's order being more than 2 and have the same number of vertices and edges be non-isomorphic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it's possible. For example take $n=6$ and each of the vertices have degree $3$. Then you can construct $K_{3,3}$ the complete bipartite graph on $6$ vertices and also another graph which isn't bipartite. The second graph can be obtained by constructing two distinct $C_3$ cycles and then connecting three pairs of vertices from distinct cycles. As both don't share a property (namely bipartivity) then they can't be isomorphic to each other.

You can find a picture of the two non-isomoprhic graphs [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82202/isomorphic-regular-graphs).

Comment: That other graph could be visualised as the edges of a triangular prism.